# Google In App Billing My App Name is not showing.Its Show "Sample Title ". Why?

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I have uploaded Signed .apk on google Play.I have added In-App Billing files on my project but when I click on In App Purchase It show

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnTvN.png  this.

I'm following http://www.androidhub4you.com/2013/03/how-to-inegrate-in-app-purchase-billing.html tutorial.Kindly help me how can I put my app's name on this dialogue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done this issue by putting my products id in place of android.test.purchased.Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are using `android.test.purchased` SKU. Use your own and you will see the title you set in the Developer Console.